# AAR File generate from React Native CLI init Project

Tags: android, react-native

I want to generate aar file that we can share with 3rd party affiliate, from React native application generated from React native CLI similar to npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject. I am able to generate apk file using gradlew command. But not got anything related to aar file generation

Comment: Did you get solution for your question?